# Can I make Jupyter QtConsole use specific font?

Tags: fonts, jupyter-console

I like the [DejaVu](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page) fonts and want to use *DejaVu Sans Mono* as my Jupyter qtconsole's font. I use the following command:

```
/opt/local/anaconda/bin/jupyter qtconsole \
   --JupyterWidget.font_family="DejaVu" \
   --JupyterWidget.font_size=11 \
   --JupyterWidget.height=40 \
   --JupyterWidget.width=80 --style=emacs
```

But it seems the setting of `JupyterWidget.font_family` does not work.

I've reviewed the [Jupyter's official document about configuration](https://jupyter.org/qtconsole/stable/config_options.html) and found only two setting related to font, font family and size. So, is there a way to specify the font?

My system is Linux Mint Debian 2, and Jupyter QtConsole is 4.2.1. And I'm sure the *DejaVu* fonts have been installed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/IPython/comments/5233uw/can_i_make_jupyter_qtconsole_use_specific_font/), I've found the answer.

There is a error in my setting. The `JupyterWidget.font_family` should be set as `DejaVu Sans Mono`.